# Performing a relational Query and selecting distinct records by the combination of two columns in MySql

Tags: php, yii, mysqli

I have two tables in my database, users and user activities, The user table has id, first_name,last_name and other fields, the user activities table has, id, user_id (foreign key --> from the users table) and project id. I want to select distinct user names (combination of first and last name) where project_id is 1.

If I write this as a simple query it works fine, the query I wrote was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.first_name,users.last_name,`user_activities`.user_id FROM `users`
JOIN `user_activities`
ON users.id=`user_activities`.user_id 
WHERE project_id=2;
```

How do i perform this query in YII?

Comment: perform in yii? what method you need to use? CDbCriteria or query builder? in any of the case what you have tried so far?

Comment: @RafayZiaMir sir I am new to YII so thats why didnt had much of the knowledge, after your comment I searched and searched thoroughly, tried the CDb criteria and built the relations as well, finally now I am able to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two approaches.

1. Simple Query Builder

[See this.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder)

2) Relations to user table on user activities.

[See this.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr)

And at least, give it a try. And update, where you get stuck.

Comment: I studied about YII relations and defined some relations of many-many and belongs to etc and finally I am starting to get my desired results.

Comment: Glad to hear that. You did it finally.